# List Index Out Of Range error when not out of range

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a data file which only contains the following line:

```
"testA" "testB":1:"testC":2
```

Now when I split this line, and print the resulting list(w) I get the following:

```
['"testA"', '"testB":1:"testC":2']

[]
```

Now when I want to access `w[0]`, it returns `"testA"` just fine, but when I print `w[1]`, it crashes and gives a list index out of range error, but *still prints it out* `"testB":1:"testC":2`

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error. Perhaps you should provide the actual traceback of the exception with an [edit] and maybe a [mcve] that does cause an error

Comment: It does not crash on `w[1]`; it crashes on `w[0]` for _the second line_!

Comment: Please show your code, it's impossible to tell what you're doing from the description.

Comment: the problem is with the second list `[]`, is empty therefore there is no position 0 in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that the program read the next line after the first one which it split, and that line was empty. So as soon as it tried to index the content of that (empty line) it crashed. That's why it DID print the first line, and then crashed. Thanks a lot for your help, though!

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not crash on `w[1]` on the `"testA" "testB":1:"testC":2` line, otherwise it would *not* print `"testB":1:"testC":2`. Note the additional `[]` in your output? Your file contains some more empty lines, which are split to `[]`, and which will then produce that error even on `w[0]`.

To fix the problem, you should check whether the `line` and/or the list created from that line is non-empty. (When testing the line, make sure to strip away any whitespace, such as the trailing newline character.) Your code should then look somewhat like this:

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():  # strip the `\n` before checking whether line is empty
            w = line.split()
            print(w[0], w[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

working for me without any error:

```
>>> a = '"testA" "testB":1:"testC":2'
>>> b = a.split(' ')
>>> b
['"testA"', '"testB":1:"testC":2']
>>> b[0]
'"testA"'
>>> b[1]
'"testB":1:"testC":2'
```

ae you doing anything different?

Comment: I think file include some unvisible characters or something else.

Comment: I don't think the file has invisible characters as I created it from within my IDE, the only thing it contains is the line I stated. It might have to do something with the extra brackets at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I also cannot reproduce your error but want to share a tip that I use in situations where I'm reading from a file and splitting on a delimiter.

```
cleaned_list = [ a.strip() for a in input_line.split(' ') if a ]
```

Simple and sanitizes the split list well.